# Registering as an Apple Developer as a sole proprietor using a dba (doing business as)

Tags: ios-appstore

Is it possible to use a "dba" (doing business as) when registering as an Apple Developer as a sole proprietor? The objective would be to have the "dba" show up as the developer in the App Store, instead of the legal name of the sole proprietor person.

Please note that this question is specifically about being a sole proprietor. Registering an LLC is not an option here.

Comment: Why don‘t you ask Apple directly about this?

Answer (score 1):

## Contact Apple

You should [contact Apple iTunes directly](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) about this question. The answer will depend on your geographic region and exact legal status.

### Business Name

Apple appear to enforce the use of the **registered business name**. For sole traders and similar business structures, this means your personal name.

See [Does app store display sole trader's name and home address?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/74308) for a related Apple Developer Forum discussion:

> The only way to not display your name is if you have a company/LLC, in which case gather the related documentation and contact Apple via the Contact Us tree found in iTunes Connect.